# MySQL Select Depending on Results

Tags: mysql

I have a table with fruits:

```
id    fruit_type    color
--------------------------
 1      apple      yellow
 2      apple      green
 3    strawberry    red
```

I want to select all fruits from my table. But if it's an apple, I only want to include it if it's green.
How can I achieve that in a single MySQL query?

Comment: quite an interesting scenario:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing complicated, you just have to use a `OR` operator in your `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM fruits
WHERE fruit_type != "apple"
OR color = "green"; /* ie where fruit_type = "apple" and color = "green" */
```

.

Comment: I dv'd apparently. Can't remember why :-\

Answer (score 0):

I  think you could use union.

```
Select * from fruits where fruit_type<> 'apple'    
Union
Select * from fruits where fruit_type= 'apple' and color = 'green'
```

Comment: On a large scale, this is quite inefficient. There are operators like `OR` that can be used for this.

Comment: I agree but its not mentioned in question if he is considering performance. I just wanted to show alternative

Comment: Is this what I think it is: First all fruits get selected that aren't apples, and then this result is merged with all apples that are green?

Comment: @BenediktB yes u understand well

Answer (score 0):

here i create query for `sql server`. same way you can create in `mysql`

```
Select id, fruit_type,color from
(
Select 
Case when fruit_type = 'apple' and color <> 'Green'
then 'N' Else 'Y' end as selected, 
*
from fruits )temptable
where temptable.selected = 'Y'
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26f1d/9)